# How to generate report using SAP Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Good day,I am new to SAP Crystal Reporting. I have a problem dealing with generating reports using SAP Crystal Reports for weeks seems cannot find the answer. The scenario is this one;

I have 2 tables:

1. dbo.Requestor
2. dbo.Designation

**dbo.Requestor** has these data:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| Ctrl_No   |  Request_No   |   Description   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  001      |       1       | Description 1   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  001      |       2       | Description 2   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  002      |       1       | Description 1   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  002      |       2       | Description 2   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**dbo.Designation** has these data:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| Ctrl_No   |  Request_No   |   Tasks         |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  001      |       1       |     Task 1      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  001      |       2       |     Task 1      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  001      |       2       |     Task 2      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  002      |       1       |     Task 1      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  002      |       1       |     Task 2      |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

as shown above, **dbo.Requestor** has Ctrl_No 001 and 002 and each Ctrl_No has 2 request_No with its corresponding description. In the **dbo.Designation** each request, there is tasks assigned, in my example **dbo.Designation** shows that Request_No 1 with a Ctrl_No of 001 has been assigned of 1 task and Request_No 2 with Ctrl_No of 001 has 2 task assign and so on.

My question is, How can I populate my report in a distinct result? so it could be displayed like this (just ignore some text output):

[image]

I highlighted the text to indicate the data are related. I hope I made my question clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Request info a subreport that uses data just from the Request table.
This would avoid record duplication because there is no join to the Task table.

Comment: Thanks for the response, any steps on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

To create a sub report:

Insert - Insert Subreport

Create a subreport with Report Wizard : give it name and click on the button next to it

Choose the tables like Millet suggested and finish.